# how to get local top 10 highscore from openfeint

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, openfeint

this is my coding am used to get local top 10 highscore but , debugging terminated error occurs.

```
[OFHighScoreService getPageWithLoggedInUserForLeaderboard: theLeaderboardID onSuccess:OFDelegate(self, @selector(_scoresDownloaded:))
        onFailure:OFDelegate()];
```

selector:-

```
- (void)_scoresDownloaded:(OFPaginatedSeries*)page
{

    NSMutableArray* highscores = nil;

    if ([page count] > 0)
    {
        if ([[page objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[OFTableSectionDescription class]])
        {
            highscores = [(OFTableSectionDescription*)[page objectAtIndex:0] page].objects;
        }
        else
        {
            highscores = page.objects;
        }
    }
   NSString *userID = [OpenFeint lastLoggedInUserName];
    for (OFHighScore* score in highscores)
    {
        ccColor3B theColor = ccBLACK;
        if ([score.user.name isEqualToString: userID] ) {
            //score now contains the users data... Do what I want with it.
                        NSLog(@"%d %@ %d", score.rank, score.user.name, score.score);
                        break;

        }

    }
}
```

this is my console window error:-

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Levelone canReceiveCallbacksNow]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6af2070'
*** Call stack at first throw:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Comment: but only one score is dispalyed of local device ( top 1) . i want top 10 of local device player , whats the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, the object you are using as the callback delegate for `OFHighScoreService` does not recognize the selector `canReceiveCallbacksNow`. As per OpenFeint documentation, your callback must implement the `OFCallbackable` protocol which defines this. Simply implement the function, e.g. just have it return `YES` all the time.

Comment: very thanks for your help. but only one score is dispalyed of local device ( top 1)  . i want top 10 of local device player , whats the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

OpenFeint only stores the latest qualifying score per player on a given leaderboard.  No user would ever appear ranked at more than one slot on a leaderboard.